# ORA-00936 when select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, outer-join

```
SELECT * FROM A,B
WHERE 
A.COMP_CODE = B.COMP_CODE (+)
AND 
A.DATE = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(B.DATE,'yyyymm'),-1),'YYYYMM') (+)
```

When I execute this statement I get error: ORA-00936.
When I remove the (+) at the end this statement then it works, but I want keep (+) in this statement.

Comment: Why you need the (+)

Comment: i want table B left join with table A.

Comment: Why you do not use left join syntax

Answer (score 2):

When using the old `(+)` syntax for outer joins, the `(+)` should directly follow the column your're outer-joining on, not the entire expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM   A, B
WHERE  A.COMP_CODE = B.COMP_CODE (+)
       AND 
       A.DATE = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(B.DATE (+), 'yyyymm'), 'YYYYMM')
       -- Here -----------------------------------^
```

But honestly, this syntax has been considered deprecated for several years no. You'd probably be better off using the modern explicit `outer join` syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON -- Here!
    A.COMP_CODE = B.COMP_CODE
    AND 
    A.DATE = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(B.DATE, 'yyyymm'), 'YYYYMM')
```

Comment: Thank's you for answer.
I want select data with 3 tables.
SELECT *
FROM A as A,B as B1,B as B2
A.COMP_CODE = B1.COMP_CODE (+)
AND 
A.DATE = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(B1.DATE,'yyyymm'),-1),'YYYYMM') (+)
AND 
A.COMP_CODE = B2.COMP_CODE (+)
AND 
A.DATE = TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(B2.DATE,'yyyymm'),-2),'YYYYMM') (+)

can you resolve with LEFT OUTER JOIN for me?
Thank's

Comment: @XuânTrọngNguyễn - you have been shown the principle of the ANSI syntax. How many attempt do you think it would take you to find the correct formulation for three tables?